# Nuxt 3 fetch issue when using internal routing

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, nuxt.js, nuxt3

I have two pages:

First:

```
<template>
    <Layout>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="border border-[red] mt-4 w-max">
                <NuxtLink :to="localePath({name: 'products'})">Product List</NuxtLink>
            </div>

            <div>
                <p>{{$t('page.language_picker')}}</p>
                <NuxtLink v-for="language in languages" class="p-2 cursor-pointer transition-colors" :class="{'bg-main-blue': chosenLanguage===language.name}" :key="language.name" :to="switchLocalePath(language.name)">{{language.name}}</NuxtLink>

            </div>
        </div>
    </Layout>
</template>
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';
import Layout from "../layouts/Layout.vue";
const switchLocalePath = useSwitchLocalePath()
const { locale, t } = useI18n();

const  localePath  = useLocalePath()

const chosenLanguage = ref(locale.value)

const languages = ref([
    {
        name: 'pl',
    },
    {
        name: 'en',
    }
])



</script>
```

Second:

```
<template>
    <Layout>
        <div class="container">
            <p>products/index.vue</p>
            <NuxtLink :to="localePath({ name: 'products-category', params: { category: 'test' } })">
                Products-Category
            </NuxtLink>
            <div>
                <p>Products</p>
                <p>{{ data }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </Layout>
</template>

<script setup>
import Layout from "../../layouts/Layout.vue";

const config = useRuntimeConfig();

const { data, error } = await useFetch(`${config.public.baseUrl}/api/products/`)
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Whenever I'm clicking  from first one to get to second I'm getting error:

*Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: can't access property "parentNode", node is null*

but when I'm going directly to seconds page URL or just refresh page data load correctly.
How can I fix that?

Comment: What is inside `Layout.vue`? I'd think the problem lies somewhere in there, not in those two pages.

Comment: @Ellrohir
Layout.vue looks like this:
<template>
    <NuxtLayout class="flex flex-col min-h-screen">
        <slot/>
    </NuxtLayout>
</template>

<script setup>

const {isErrorPage} = defineProps({
    isErrorPage: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    }
});

</script>

<style>

</style>

Comment: And your main `app.vue`? I suspect the problem might be you should have `app => NuxtLayout => NuxtPage` hierarchy and since you are importing layout into each page (which is, afaik, not the way it is meant to be used), you have `app => NuxtPage => NuxtLayout`. Which might work for the first time, but then Nuxt struggles while trying to update the DOM during routing. But it is just a wild guess so far.